# Problems validating a checkbox

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, checkbox

I've a problem validating a checkbox - the error message doesn't show up.

Here is the validating code:

```
if ( '#yesno'.val() == ''){
                    $('#yesno').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("Du har inte kryssat i rutan");
                    err++;
                }
```

It is a part of multi-step form - here is the code where the checkbox is

```
           var step3_validation = function(){
            var err = 0;

            if($('#boende').val() == '0'){
                $('#boende').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("Välj ett boendealternativ");
                err++;
            }
            if ( '#yesno'.val() == ''){
                $('#yesno').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("Du har inte kryssat i rutan");
                err++;
            }
            if(err == 0){
                $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-error").addClass("step-success");
                $(".rhino-next").show();
                $('.form-submit').hide();
                $('.rhino-next').trigger('click');
            }else{
                $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-success").addClass("step-error");
            }

        };
```

And here is the checkbox:

```
                                <div class="form-left2">Jag har läst <a href="#">cupinformationen</a></div>
                            <div class="form-right2"><input type="checkbox" name="yesno" value="check1"></div>
                            <div class="form-error"></div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if ( '#yesno'.val() == ''){
```

to

```
if ( $('#yesno').val() == ''){
```

You could have found the error [using the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) : an error message should indicate that the `val` function wasn't found.